# Fedora not shutting down

Tags: linux, shutdown, fedora

Whether I do `shutdown -P now` or `sudo shutdown --halt now` Fedora does not shutdown. It will send SIGTERM and SIGKILL as usual, but then just stops at the screen with the fedora logo. My only option is to hold the power button down, which is obviously not the best option for shutting down.

This started at my last kernel upgrade, `3.5.16` 11 days ago.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Fedora 20 or later, do any interesting messages show when you run `journalctl`?

Comment: I honestly don't know enough to figure out what journalctl gives.

Comment: You would want to look at the messages around the time that you shut the box down. Ones where the system is waiting for processes to finish and never complete will be of most interest. Also, make sure that you run `sudo journalctl` if you aren't logged in as `root`

Comment: `sudo journalctl | grep shutdown` returns a lot about things receiving signal 15 (SIGTERM). The only two things it lists are dhclient and NetworkManager, along with my `shutdown` commands.

Comment: How long have you waited for the computer to shutdown?

Comment: I generally give it a minute or two after the message `reached target Shutdown` but haven't tried waiting too long.