# Fedora 22 does not shut down

Tags: fedora

I installed Fedora 22 a few days ago and noticed that at times it didn't shut down. The monitor received no signal and goes black. But the color in the power button is still on and the fans of the CPU are still running.

I found a similar question here ([Fedora not shutting down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147346/fedora-not-shutting-down)) but there was no clear answer.

I ran `journalctl` as root and here's the last part of the outcome before I turned the computer off myself by holding the power button. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
  Jul 30 21:53:43 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[720]: System is powering down.
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[1920]: gnome-session[1920]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain gnome-session[1920]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Session 1 of user gglasses.
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Session 1 of user gglasses.
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Restore /run/initramfs on shutdown...
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain audit[2009]: <audit-1701> auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain polkitd[738]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.54, object path /org/fre
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for power management...
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Sound Card.
Jul 30 21:53:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/mapper/fedora-swap...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Disk Manager...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 PV scan on device 8:1...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Graphical Interface.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Multi-User System.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.0 database server...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Job spooling tools...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping ABRT kernel log watcher...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Command Scheduler...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping NTP client/server...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain chronyd[688]: chronyd exiting
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping SYSV: Late init script for live image....
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Removed slice system-getty.slice.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping system-getty.slice.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Login Prompts.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Install ABRT coredump hook...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 42...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping GNOME Display Manager...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Store Sound Card State.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounting RPC Pipe File System...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain audit[1524]: <audit-1701> auid=4294967295 uid=42 gid=42 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:xdm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of user gdm.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of user gdm.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[2098]: Terminating
Jul 30 21:53:46 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[2098]: Stopping SDP server
Jul 30 21:53:46 localhost.localdomain bluetoothd[2098]: Exit
Jul 30 21:53:47 localhost.localdomain dbus[696]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Accounts' unit='accounts-daemon.servi
Jul 30 21:53:48 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[695]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Jul 30 21:53:48 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[695]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.5.
Jul 30 21:53:48 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[695]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 exiting.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.hostname:
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own: (0) 
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system: (
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: (0) Auth
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: (0)
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain dbus[696]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'accounts-daemon.service': Refusing activation, D-Bu
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain alsactl[683]: alsactl daemon stopped
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control: (0) Auth
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Authorization Manager.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Daemon for power management.
Jul 30 21:53:45 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped PackageKit Daemon.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopped target Default.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopping Default.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopping Basic System.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopping Sockets.
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopping Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Starting Shutdown.
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Starting Shutdown.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopped target Default.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Power Off Screen...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopping Default.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Stopping Paths.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopping Basic System.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopping Sockets.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1751]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 11141 (kill).
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopping Timers.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Starting Exit the Session...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Stopping Paths.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit firewalld.service entered failed state.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: firewalld.service failed.
 Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=cr
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=ud
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=co
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=bl
Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=ht
  Jul 30 21:53:49 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=ab
Jul 30 21:53:51 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=li
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=al
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=fi
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=db
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=gd
Jul 30 21:53:56 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <warn>  disconnected by the system bus.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1754]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user gglasses
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1256]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 11153 (kill).
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1280]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user gdm
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 42.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=us
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Removed slice user-42.slice.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping user-42.slice.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Permit User Sessions...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-launch-environment
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: Freeing conversation 'gdm-launch-environment' with active job
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: Freeing conversation 'gdm-password' with active job
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: Failed to contact accountsservice: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDB
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: Child process -1385 was already dead.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain gdm[876]: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd[696]: Exception KeyError: KeyError(140594674702080,) in <module 'threading' f
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream retur
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain abrtd[725]: The name 'org.freedesktop.problems.daemon' has been lost, please check if other service owning the 
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: abrtd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit abrtd.service entered failed state.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: abrtd.service failed.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=ab
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Init script for live image....
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Init script for live image..
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=li
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Permit User Sessions.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping User and Group Name Lookups.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Remote File Systems.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Remote File Systems (Pre).
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target NFS client services.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping NFS client services.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping GSSAPI Proxy Daemon...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown...
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain iscsiadm[11167]: iscsiadm: No matching sessions found
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=is
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped WPA Supplicant daemon.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=wp
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped GSSAPI Proxy Daemon.
Jul 30 21:53:57 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=gs
Jul 30 21:53:59 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <info>  Could not connect to the system bus; only the private D-Bus socket will be availab
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/fedora/swap.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/fba815ca-5c6d-4669-a933-2b4e6909afdb.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-urmOqowfmjzlClU7g4S7DynV15ytZJ2wQnrOcQP4Z4C1HEGYRk6sPw
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-fedora-swap.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/dm-0.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/mapper/fedora-swap.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[1080]: 150730 21:54:00 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.0 database server.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Network.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Network.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=ma
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <info>  caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[802]: <info>  exiting (success)
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=Ne
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Basic System.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped dnf makecache timer.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping dnf makecache timer.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Sockets.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Closed Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Open-iSCSI iscsiuio Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Closed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Closed Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Open-iSCSI iscsid Socket.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Closed CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Slices.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Slices.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Removed slice User and Session Slice.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping User and Session Slice.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Paths.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target System Initialization.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping System Initialization.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Apply Kernel Variables...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Swap.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Encrypted Volumes.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Encrypted Volumes.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Setup Virtual Console.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Setup Virtual Console...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Security Auditing Service...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
lines 233633-233668
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain auditd[674]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1305 audit(1438314840.965:1580): audit_pid=0 old=674 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=sy
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314840.967:1581): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314840.969:1582): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314840.969:1583): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314840.999:1584): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Security Auditing Service.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Import network configuration from initramfs.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Import network configuration from initramfs...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Local File Systems.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounting Configuration File System...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/user/42...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/user/1000/gvfs...
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted Configuration File System.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/42.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000/gvfs.
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit: <audit-1305> audit_pid=0 old=674 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=1
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=au
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=fe
Jul 30 21:54:00 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lv
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted Temporary Directory.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.011:1585): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain lvm[11213]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" unmonitored
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lv
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted Temporary Directory.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.011:1585): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain lvm[11213]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "fedora" unmonitored
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/user/1000...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Configure read-only root support.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Configure read-only root support...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=fe
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.024:1586): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.026:1587): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lv
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/user/1000.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Unmount All Filesystems.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Local File Systems (Pre).
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Shutdown.

Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Final Step.
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.041:1588): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1438314841.041:1589): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:s
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
Jul 30 21:54:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1]: <audit-1131> pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sy
-- Reboot --
```

Comment: Is this F22 with all updates applied?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have a service that is breaking the powering off.

In my case was the apache service.

So I just run **systemctl stop httpd.service** and I worked.